# How do I split my bed bim and fam files by family ID in plink?

Tags: split, plink

I want to split my bed, bim and fam files by family ID in plink.
For example, I can do this by chromosome by typing:

```
p-link --bfile datafile1 --chr 1 --make-bed --out datafile2
```

And that makes a separate bed, bim and fam file for chromosome 1.

However, in my fam file, I have several different family IDs that I want to split the files by.  For example

```
Family 1 TS11339 0 0 2 -9
Family 1 TS11233 0 0 2 -9
Family 2 TF99288 0 0 2 -9
Family 2 YJ22997 0 0 2 -9
Family 3 YF00277 0 0 2 -9
Family 3 YY92779 0 0 2 -9
```

I want to have Family1.bed -.bim and -.bam, Family2.bed -.bim and -.bam etc.

How can I do this?
(Sorry for poor knowledge - just started using plink).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, you can do it via plink as follows:

p-link --bfile datafile1 --keep LIST1.txt --make-bed --out

Where LIST1.txt is a list of family ID's and individuals.  So say if you wanted to extract Family 1, LIST1.txt would consist of:

> Family 1 TS11339
>
> Family 1 TS11233

More information can be found at the plink website.

Answer (score 2):

The following command should split the plink dataset on a UNIX shell:

```
for fam in $(awk '{print $1}' datafile1.fam | sort | uniq); do echo $fam | plink --bfile datafile1 --keep-fam /dev/stdin --make-bed --out $fam; done
```

Comment: This works perfectly if you want to split your files in new files with only one family each, specially if you have many families and don't want to extract each one manually. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

A bit simpler: plink [--keep-fam](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink2/filter#indiv) .